# How do you efficiently connect to mysql in php without reconnecting on every query

Tags: php, mysql, connection-pooling

I'm pretty sick of having to rewrite my code every time I learn something new about php (like the fact that mysql connections cannot be passed around in a session as a handle).

How do you implement mysql connection in your projects? A lot of people have proposed "connection pooling", but after reading the manual i'm still lost. It's like: "connection pooling is mysql_pconnect!" - me: "and...? how is that any different in reality? can you pass around a mysql_pconnect in a session? why is this seemingly mysterious aura??"

Let me explain my situation. I have a function called "query1":

```
function query1($query)
{
    $db = new mysql(HOST,USER,PASS,DBNAME);
    $result = $db->query($query);
    $db->close();
    return $result;
}
```

This is seems like a squanderous and inefficient way of querying a db (**especially** since you need a mysql handle for functions like mysql_real_escape_string). *What is the correct form to do it? Can someone please help me?*

Thank you I'd really appreciate a good honest answer.

Comment: @Gal read my most recent update. It provides a solution that doesn't require variables.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Normally connections happen once a page load. AKA

```
class Database{
    public function connect()
    {
         $this->connection = mysql_connect();
    }

    // This will be called at the end of the script.
    public function __destruct()
    {
        mysql_close($this->connection);
    }

    public function query($query)
    {
        return mysql_query($query, $this->connection);
    }
}
$database = new Database;
$database->connect();

$database->query("INSERT INTO TABLE (`Name`) VALUES('Chacha')");
```

Basically, you open the connection in the beginning of the page, close it at the end page. Then, you can make various queries during the page and don't have to do anything to the connection.

You could even do the mysql_connect in the constructor as Erik suggest.

---

To use the above using global variables (not suggested as it creates global state), you would do something like

```
Global $db;

$db = new Database;
// ... do startup stuff

function doSomething()
{
    Global $db;
    $db->query("Do Something");
}
```

---

Oh, and no one mentioned you don't have to pass around a parameter. Just connect

```
mysql_connect();
```

Then, mysql_query will just use the last connection no matter what the scope is.

```
mysql_connect();

function doSomething()
{
    mysql_query("Do something");
}
```

---

Per the comments:

> I think you should use mysql_pconnect() instead of mysql_connect(), because mysql_connect() doesn't use connection pooling. – nightcoder

You might want to consider whether you use `mysql_connect` or `mysql_pconnect`. However, you should still only connect once per script.

Comment: but it's ludicrous to start passing $db handle to every function I use on each page (which is an extremely daunting and superfluous task).
thanks anyway.

Comment: I don't know a ton about OO programming, but why wouldn't you just connect in the constructor? Seems like adding a 2nd step after "new Database" is unnecessary.

Comment: Added that in Erik. I really haven't created a full class as I don't even pass in user info. Just offering a solution.

Comment: @Chacha102 I don't think I am. There's just gotta be a better method of doing this ubiquitous task. I mean, do all 1,000,000 PHP programmers connect to mysql this way? with all the respect, i really doubt it.

Comment: @Gal, no one mentioned that mysql_query just uses the last connection to mysql. Just `mysql_connect` in the beginning of the script, and then use `mysql_query` throughout your script.

Comment: @Chacha102 thanks, I'm gonna try that, I actually didn't know that. I hope that'll work for me.

Comment: @Gal, you might want to read the manual. It is right on the `mysql_query` page. http://us2.php.net/mysql_query

Comment: I think you should use mysql_pconnect() instead of mysql_connect(), because mysql_connect() doesn't use connection pooling.

Comment: @nightcoder, I'll add that to the answer. Per the documentation, you should be able to use mysql_connect just as well, but connection pooling is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to connect to the database in every function. You need to connect to the database when the script starts running and save connection object in global state. In any function you can use that connection object to query the database. Your connection object will be recreated for every time script is executed but it will be very fast, because special connection pool is used behind the scene, so connection will be done immediately (matter of microseconds, because actually connection was not even broken, it was saved in connection pool).

Here is the example you asked for:

```
// this code should be executed on every page/script load:
$adoConn = ADONewConnection(...);
$adoConn->PConnect(...);

// ...

//And then in any place you can just write:
global $adoConn;
$adoConn->ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO test SET Value = 'Hello, world!'");
```

As for your question "how do I implement connection pool". You don't. It's maintained by the server behind the scene and used if you (or the PHP library for work with PHP) use mysql_pconnect() function.

PS. If you are afraid to keep $adoConn as a global variable (I'm not) then you can create a class with a static property:

```
class DB
{
  public static $adoConn;
}

// ...

DB::$adoConn->ExecuteNonQuery(...);
```

Comment: thank you, but can you please provide me with some code? you mentioned global state. is that like define("db",$db)? how do I implement connection pool with this method?

Comment: Its basically you have to `Global $db` in every function and where you define `$db`. I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: Does this require me to have global variables turned on? Isn't this a security breach?

Comment: Global variables can't be turned on or off. It is a feature of PHP, and not really. `register_globals` is something completely different.

Comment: Register Globals is an abomination but what Chacha suggests has nothing to do with Register Globals. Creating global variables yourself has a place in PHP - RG refers to globals created automatically based on form input names which can potentially clobber variables you've created and do nasty things you hadn't anticipated.

Comment: No, this isn't a security break.