# PHP PDO lastInsertId() returns 0 after inserting into table, No Errors or Warnings

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to get the ID # that is inserted into a MYSQL database after a record is inserted (using auto-increment).  I am using PHP PDO lastInsertId().  I'm using PHP version 7.4 and MySQL version 8.0.16.

Here are my classes and code. I have removed some of the column names and replaced with "..." for brevity.

```
class DB {

private $servername;
private $username;
private $password;
private $dbname;

protected function connect() {
    $this->servername ="removed";
    $this->username ="removed";
    $this->password ="removed";
    $this->dbname ="removed";

    
    try {
        $dsn = "mysql:host=".$this->servername.";dbname=".$this->dbname; //Data Source Name
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $this->username, $this->password);
        //$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $pdo;
    } catch(\Exception $exception) {
        echo("Connection Failed: ".$exception->getMessage());
        die();
    }
 

   }
}

    class Product extends DB
    {
    public function addProduct(int $CategoryID, int $BrandID....)
        {        
                $sql = "INSERT into products (CategoryID, BrandID, ....) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute([$CategoryID, $BrandID, .....]);
                $ProductID = $this->connect()->lastInsertId();            
        }
}
```

The code inserts a record into the DB, assigns a unique identifier, but then returns a 0 for $ProductID.  I checked my logs and there are no errors or warnings from PHP. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the same database connection for inserting the row and fetching the ID. Do **not** reconnect in between.

Your `addProduct` method could look like:

```
public function addProduct(int $CategoryID, int $BrandID....)
    {        
            $connection = $this->connect();
            $sql = "INSERT into products (CategoryID, BrandID, ....) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute([$CategoryID, $BrandID, .....]);
            $ProductID = $connection->lastInsertId();            
    }
```

It would be even better to introduce a class variable to store that DB connection. For examples, you could check [Use PDO database class without creating new connection every time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42117982/use-pdo-database-class-without-creating-new-connection-every-time)

---

Also, please rethink your class structure. Using a DB class is already a good start, but model classes should not extend the DB class, as they are not instances of a database itself, but of a single entity or table

Comment: OK, thank you very much. I will make some edits and see what I can come up with.  I'm just learning PDO and OOP.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks, changing my Method to the way you have it has it has it working now. Thanks for all your help!